# Capifony + Symfony2 Failed to write cache file

Tags: symfony, deployment, capifony

When deploying my dev environment to my external dev server using capistrano I always get the following error:

```
RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/xyz.co.uk/app/cache/dev/classes.php".
```

Then I have to log into my development server and delete my app/cache/dev/ directory.

Here is my development.rb file:

```
server 'x.xx.xx.xxx', :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
ssh_options[:port] = 1234
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/xyz.co.uk"
set :symfony_env_prod, "dev"
set :branch, "develop"

# Need to clear *_dev controllers
set :clear_controllers,     false
```

And my deploy.rb file:

```
set :stage_dir, 'app/config/deploy' # needed for Symfony2 only
set :stages, %w(production staging development)
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application,           "xyz.co.uk"
set :user,                  "root"  # The server's user for deploys

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :repository,            "git@github.com:xyz/xyz.co.uk.git"
set :scm,                   :git
set :keep_releases,         3
set :use_sudo,              false
set :web_path,              "web"
set :shared_files,          ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,       [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads"]
set :use_composer,          true
set :update_vendors,        true
set :dump_assetic_assets,   true
set :deploy_via,            :remote_cache

#logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Comment: This is most likely a permission issue.

Comment: Because Im deploying as root? How do you set the cache and logs permissions when deploying?

Comment: You should not deploy as root because it's a major security issue. A better idea is to create a separate user just for deployment. Or, if you're the only one deployer, you could deploy as yourself.

Comment: Thanks Elnur. To create a separate user, do I need to create the user e.g deployer in GIT and also give the user (deployer) SSH access to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this in my `deploy.rb` file to set the permissions on the cache directory:

```rb
after "deploy:update_code" do
  capifony_pretty_print "--> Ensuring cache directory permissions"
  run "setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX #{latest_release}/#{cache_path}"
  run "setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX #{latest_release}/#{cache_path}"
  capifony_puts_ok
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deploying as `root`, so you have to use `sudo`:

```
set :use_sudo, true
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo though should you? Would it be best to use a different user? Would the user have to be www-data though?

Comment: Since you mentioned that you use user `root` to deploy, then you have to specify the line I mention. In general, deploying it as root is not a good idea, but your question was not about it :) Using `www-data` is much better idea.

Comment: I've gone for @Elnur Abdurrakhimov approach as this allows me to use the root user but still set the correct permissions on the cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
set :webserver_user,      "www-data"
set :permission_method,   :acl
set :use_set_permissions, true
```

Make sure that you have acl enabled. If not, refer to this link http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/symfony2-file-permissions-in-ubuntu/